# "one of [something]" for multiple cases?

Tags: sentence-construction

Let's say there are two tables of specs of two different products and each of those products is from its respective product line.

So, I want to say

-The two tables are for each product

-Each product is one model of their group (A and B)

This is the sentence I come up with:

```
The tables above are for the two products that are
[one / ones]
[of / from]
Product Series A and Product Series B each.
```

I would like to know if it's one or ones and of or from in the sentence and if there's a better-constructed sentence.

Comment: Why not  
Table 1 is for a product from Series A. Table 2 is for a product from Series B. Or, the tables above are for products from Series A and B, along with appropriate labels on the tables.

Comment: The tables contain the same type of information (table headers) so that's why I want to construct a sentence like that. But I guess that could work.